# NameError("name 'message' is not defined")

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, telebot

В Telegram Bot API возникает вот такая ошибка NameError("name 'message' is not defined") . Возникает когда выбираю iPhone из Catalogo. Подскажите как и почему возникает ошибка. Это мой первый бот.

```
import telebot
import config
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def welcome(message):

    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Catalogo")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Regole")
    markup.add(item1, item2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Benvenuto, {0.first_name}!\nIo sono - <b>{1.first_name}</b>.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
    parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])

def risposta(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == "Catalogo":

            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 1)

            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone", callback_data = "iPhone")
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Samsung", callback_data = "Samsung")
            item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Huawei", callback_data = "Huawei")
            item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Xiaomi", callback_data = "Xiaomi")
            item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Nokia", callback_data = "Nokia")
            item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("LG", callback_data = "LG")

            markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Scegliete cosa vi interessa:", reply_markup=markup)


        elif message.text == "Regole":
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, " 1)Dovete vivere a Roma.\n2)Il pagamento viene effettuato dopo aver scielto il telefono.\n3)")

        else :
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Scusate non ho capito")

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)

def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'iPhone':
                markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width = 3)

                item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone 11 Pro Max", callback_data = "iPhone 11 Pro Max")
                item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone 11 Pro", callback_data = "iPhone 11 Pro")
                item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone 11", callback_data = "iPhone 11")
                item4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone XS Max", callback_data = "iPhone XS Max")
                item5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone XS", callback_data = "iPhone XS")
                item6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone XR", callback_data = "iPhone XR")
                item7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone X", callback_data = "iPhone X")
                item8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone 8 Plus", callback_data = "iPhone 8 Plus")
                item9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone 8", callback_data = "iPhone 8")
                item10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone 7 Plus", callback_data = "iPhone 7 Plus")
                item11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone 7", callback_data = "iPhone 7")
                item12 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone SE", callback_data = "iPhone SE")
                item13 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone 6s Plus", callback_data = "iPhone 6s Plus")
                item14 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone 6s", callback_data = "iPhone 6s")
                item15 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone 6 Plus", callback_data = "iPhone 6 Plus")
                item16 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("iPhone 6", callback_data = "iPhone 6")

                markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7, item8, item9, item10, item11, item12, item13, item14, item15, item16)
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Scegliete il modello:", reply_markup=markup)

            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text="Catalogo",
            reply_markup=None)

    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: *Подскажыте как и почему возникает ошыбка* - потому что не определена переменная `message` на момент обращения к ней.

Comment: @Михаил Муругов
Ошабка возникает в функции def callback_inline(call):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я забыл поставить call в  `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Scegliete il modello:", reply_markup=markup)` .

Comment: А можно подробнее куда call ставить?

Comment: @GAndrew Я перешел на Aiogram, у меня больше нет этого кода, мне жаль что я не могу тебе помочь